# How to have zpaq extract files to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, compression

I have some log files compressed with ZPAQ that I do not want to extract to disk every time I need to go grep-ing for events.  Would like to extact to stdout so I can handle the output the same way as GZ compressed files with gzcat:

```
# gzcat logfile.gz | grep foobarEVENT

# zpaq l logfile.zpaq 
zpaq v6.42 journaling archiver, compiled Nov 20 2013
Reading archive logfile.zpaq

 Ver  Date      Time (UT) Attr           Size Ratio  File
----- ---------- -------- ------ ------------ ------ -------
>   1                              3873434570 0.0359 logfile
1 of 1 files shown. 3873434570 -> 139125985

Ver Last frag Date      Time (UT) Files Deleted   Original MB  Compressed MB
---- -------- ---------- -------- ------ ------ -------------- --------------
   1        1                          1      0    3873.434670     139.125985
0.529 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I was able to pass uncompressed zpaq files through the typical stdout was to make a fifo named pipe and uncompress to that fifo in one process and then read from the fifo in another process.

For example:

```
$ mkfifo data_logfile
$ zpaq x logfile -force -to data_ &
$ grep searchTeXt data_logfile > grep_results.txt
```